# CURL vs Direct Database connection in PHP

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, curl

I have a big website with heavy user load. I am using the Codeigniter framework. I am using an in-motion dedicated server.

I have build API for my web application and right now I am using CURL to call them and both web application and API are on the same server. What should I use Directly DB or PHP CURL?

What should I use?

Comment: your question is unclear, does the API access the same DB as the web app?

Comment: Using cURL when you don't have to is a waste of system resources and will slow down the user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API or Directly accessing DB to fetch data depends upon your need. Both has their pros and cons.

**Using API:** Making an api is good if there is scope to have mobile application in future or want to update front end(Migrating to JS frameword like angular) technology. But if don't have such a requirement than it costs more effort to fetch data than directly from database.

**Accessing DB Directly:**  This is simple and fast without having extra activity of curl to fetch data.

Comment: But what if we do cURL on JSON file i mean we have same data as database in JSON too.

Comment: So should i use cURL to JSON file now or directly call Database to get records??

Comment: You can directly read json file as well if it lies on save server. As: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("path/to/file/on/server"), true);` Read about `json_decode` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: yes, it's on same server. Is file_get_contents better then curl ?

Comment: Yes, it's better to use `file_get_contents` rather than using extra code for `curl`.